# What causes Node.js to interfere with JQuery code and how can I prevent it?

Tags: jquery, node.js

This is a bit strange (to me at least) but hopefully not to someone here. I have a website that uses node js only for a specific purpose that is needed rarely but needed just the same. I recently discovered that the 404 html files were not being loaded when a file wasn't found on the site due to node js. I corrected that by adding the following code in my app.js file:

```
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendfile('__dirname + "/404.shtml");
    )};
```

Problem solved. However, this created a new issue. Now jquery code from an html file (nowhere near that directory) is broken. When I debugged the code, it was loading jquery 3.0.0 which caused the error. The html file requires (and exclusively includes) the 3.1.1 jquery file.

When I remove the mentioned code from app.js it all works fine again. Has anyone ever seen this? Hosting company won't help. Thanks in advance.

Not sure what to try at this point.

Comment: Does `404.shtml` reference jQuery?

Comment: I'm not sure how this could cause references to jquery to fetch the wrong version. You should be able to use the network tab of DevTools to see what JS files are being requested.

Comment: Thank you I did that. That's how I know it's using jquery 3.0.0.

Comment: Oh my gosh I think that might be it. The 404.shtml file loads jquery 3.0.0 Wow!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you Barmar! Yes. the 404.shtml did load jQuery 3.0.0 which when removed fixed that problem. However I soon discovered another. The app.get('*) caused a bunch of other issues, so I used a different strategy to deploy the 404.shtml file and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar was correct. The 404.shtml file did load jQuery 3.0.0. When removed, it fixed the issue I was having, but I was left with more strange issues due to the code I was using to deploy the shtml file.
I found another thread that recommended using the following and everything is now working properly. Put this at the end of app.js:

```
app.use(function(req,res){
  res.status(404).sendfile(__dirname + "/404.shtml");
});
```